# sort an array of object accoring to the values

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
const array =[ 
  { a: 'good car' },
  { a: 'good car1' },
  { a: 'good car2' },
  { a: 'good car3' },
  { a: 'good car4' },
  { b: 'good car1' } 
];
```

I need to sort it via values except in the case of ties. In the case of ties, the `key` is used to break the tie. I searched A LOT but couldn't use the answers as my keys in objects are not the same and also in case of the tie (values are the same), I cannot handle that. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have only one key/value pair in an object? please add your try.

Comment: what do you mean by *"in the case of ties"*? Based on the array you show, what is the expected output after sorting?

Comment: yes only one key/value

Comment: in case of ties i mean when values are the same so I should use thier keys to sort

Answer (score 4):

You could get the entries, pick the first one and destructure it to key and value and take the same for the other object, then return the chained sorting values.

```js
var array = [{ v21: 'sad sdd' }, { aaa: 'sad sdd' }, { v11: 'r err rr' }, { hf32: 'erwwer fgh' }, { z3f2: 'agfrr vbbar' }, { t142: 'gggoog  anfa' }, { u23: 'fa handle err' }];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    var [keyA, valueA] = Object.entries(a)[0],
        [keyB, valueB] = Object.entries(b)[0];
        
    return valueA.localeCompare(valueB) || keyA.localeCompare(keyB);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `sort` from es6.

try this code:

```js
const array =[ 
  { v21: 'sad sdd' },
  { v11: 'r err rr' },
  { hf32: 'erwwer fgh' },
  { z3f2: 'agfrr vbbar' },
  { t142: 'agfrr vbbar' },
  { u23: 'fa handle err' } 
]

array.sort( (x,y) => { 
  if ( Object.values(x)[0] > Object.values(y)[0] )
    return 1
  else if ( Object.values(x)[0] < Object.values(y)[0] )
    return -1
  else {
    if ( Object.keys(x)[0] > Object.keys(y)[0] )
      return 1
    else if ( Object.keys(x)[0] < Object.keys(y)[0] )
      return -1
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```js
const array =[ 
  { v21: 'sad sdd' },
  { v11: 'r err rr' },
  { hf32: 'erwwer fgh' },
  { z3f2: 'agfrr vbbar' },
  { z3f1: 'agfrr vbbar' },
  { t142: 'gggoog  anfa' },
  { u23: 'fa handle err' } 
];
array.sort((a,b) => {
      if (a[Object.keys(a)[0]] === b[Object.keys(b)[0]]) {
          return Object.keys(a)[0].localeCompare(Object.keys(b)[0]);
      }
      return a[Object.keys(a)[0]].localeCompare(b[Object.keys(b)[0]]);
});
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant without using compare function:

```
const array = [
  { v21: "sad sdd" },
  { v11: "r err rr" },
  { hf32: "erwwer fgh" },
  { z3f2: "sad sdd" },
  { t142: "gggoog  anfa" },
  { u23: "fa handle err" }
];

const result = array
  .map(item => ({
    key: Object.keys(item)[0],
    value: item[Object.keys(item)[0]]
  }))
  .map(item => `${item.value}:${item.key}`)
  .sort()
  .map(item => item.split(":"))
  .map(item => ({ [item[1]]: item[0] }));

console.log(result);
```

have to use maybe some other join char instead of ':' if it is expected in the value